# sign up screen should not appear

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a sign up screen for my app.then it goes to sign in screen.I want that when I am relaunching the app sign up screen should not appear.it should open the sign in view directly.how do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by following steps :

1 - When user successfull signs up,then you should set a string value in a global variable and save it using NSUserDefaults. Just like :

```
// After user successfully signs up..

NSString *userSignUp = @"someValue"; // set it as a global variable....
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
    setObject:valueToSave forKey:@"signUpDone"];
```

2 - Then put a condition in you appDelegate.m class. Inside the `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` method,just retrieve that value from NSUserDefaults,which you have stored at user sign up. Then on the basis of that retrieved value,set your root view controller. Just like

```
userSignUp = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
    stringForKey:@"SignUpDone"];

if([userSignUp isEqualToString:@"someValue"])
{
  // set Home screen as your root view controller...
}
else
{
  // set Sign Up screen as your root view controller..
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure about what you are aiming to do.

Maybe you should try using *NSUserDefaults* to store that your app was already launched:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"alreadyLaunchedApp"];
```

Then, at launch, you just need to check the boolean and present the right view:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
BOOL alreadyLaunchedApp = [default boolForKey:@"alreadyLaunchedApp"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSUserDefaults` to track that app is first time launch or second time and redirect them according to the state.